# How do I add zsh completion for evince with djvu files?

Tags: evince, zsh, auto-completion

I am using `zsh` (5.0.2). The auto-completion for `evince` only shows files of some predefined extensions, amongst which `pdf` and `ps` but not `djvu`.

**How to make `zsh` also autocomplete with `djvu` files on command `evince`?** Or equivalently, where are the extensions related to `evince` defined?

Two remarks:

- In `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion`, `rgrep evince` shows:

  ```
  Unix/_pspdf:#compdef evince gsbj gsdj gsdj500 gslj gslp gsnd ps2ascii ghostview mgv pstoedit pstotgif zathura
  Unix/_pdf:#compdef pdf2dsc pdf2ps pdfimages pdfinfo pdftopbm pdftops pdftotext pdfopt pdffonts kpdf apvlv evince epdfview
  ```

  Note that there is no `Unix/_djvu` file.
- In the same directory, `rgrep djvu` shows:

  ```
  X/_okular:extns="{pdf,ps,eps,dvi}(.gz|.bz2)(#c,1)|djvu|tiff|chm|cbr|cbz"
  ```

  Again, note that there is no `X/_evince` file.

I guess that possible solutions would be to add a `X/_evince` file with the right command, or a `Unix/_djvu` file with the right command but this yields some questions:

- What are the right commands to add to such files? Should I create both files I mentioned above? Will these files be automatically recognized?
- Isn't there a *cleaner* way to fix the problem, whether by modifying my `.zshrc`, installing a new package, or invoking one relevant command?